# Hide the tab in a VCL Ribbon

Tags: c++builder, vcl, c++builder-xe3

I have 2 problems with a VCL TRibbon. I am using C++ Builder XE3.

1. Extra bar along the top. There is an extra bar along the top which i cant remove. I don't see any options which effect it.
2. Is there a way to remove just the tab. I only have 1 ribbon page and there is no need for the tab with the text.

I am trying to get the icons flush against the App border.

[image]

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and include an image? I can't quite understand what you're asking. (Just the ribbon section of your form to illustrate what you're asking.) Thanks. :-)

Comment: sorry about that. Image fixed now.

Comment: The "extra bar" across the top is only shown in the IDE Form Designer. It becomes the title bar of your application when you run it (you can test this by setting the `Ribbon1.Caption` property and running the app). I'm pretty sure the tab has to be there, as it's part of the MS Fluent UI guidelines (and your application doesn't seem to be following them, BTW; you might want to research them). Without tabs, you have no need for the ribbon at all; a simple toolbar would work.

Comment: This form is actually going to be used within a .NET application using Hydra and the tab part of the ribbon is already provided by that application. I just need to a way to create a panel that would be embedded within that but i also need to keep the look and feel of the ribbon and last time i used the simple toolbar it didn't do that.

Comment: That information is probably important enough to include in your question. :-) I don't think you can use the VCL ribbon like that, as it's not written in a way that would allow it AFAICT. (It's a custom implementation of the ribbon that isn't actually based on the MS control, and I don't think you can separate out parts of it to embed in a non-VCL ribbon control.) Someone else may jump in here and say I'm all wrong about that, though. :-)